# Multiple Charts with Google Chart API

Tags: url, charts, google-api, candlestick-chart

I am interested in displaying 2 charts in the same URL call with the Google Chart API.

As an example, lets say we have the following call to the API for a single chart:

```
http://chart.apis.google.com/chart?chs=600x400&cht=lc&chd=t0:-1,5,10,7,12,-1|-1,25,45,47,24,-1|-1,40,30,27,39,-1|-1,55,63,59,80,-1&chm=F,0000FF,0,-1,20
```

I would like to display that chart, and a separate chart (with it's own axis and stuff) underneath it in the same call.

For now, it can just be a copy of the same chart, and I can modify the chart properties later.

I have working code for displaying multiple lines on the same chart, but I am interesting in 2 completely separate charts.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Could you explain a little more about why they need to be in the same call? In short, what you want is not possible. Two different requests would be needed to get the Google Charts to generate two images.

Comment: I kinda figured it was not possible, but I figured I would ask.

The reason I would like them in the same call, is because I have several different data points I wanted to plot, and when they are all on the same graph it starts getting cluttered. I want to be able to relate the data though, so having 2 plots next to each other would have been the ideal way to show it.

Comment: You should be able to just make two different calls to get two graphs and then just put the graphs next to each other in the UI. I assume you are making some kind of javascript based page?

Comment: Right now it was literally just viewing the graph in the call and not doing anything else with it. I might look at displaying it on a page like you are saying so I can make 2 different calls.